# Use if statement to only allow positive integers

Tags: r

How do I use `if` inside this R function to only allow input of positive integers for u and v?

```
pierpont <- function(pp){ 
  var1 <- readline(prompt = "Enter u value:"); 
  var2 <- readline(prompt = "Enter v value:"); 
  var1 <-as.numeric(var1); 
  var2 <-as.numeric(var2); 

c((2^var1)*(3^var2)+1) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `while` to wait until the input fulfils the conditions and `type.convert` to convert the input to an appropriate type.

```
pierpont <- function(pp) {
  var1 <- NA
  while(!is.integer(var1) | var1 < 1) {
    var1 <- type.convert(readline(prompt = "Enter u value (positive integer): "), as.is=TRUE)}
  var2 <- NA
  while(!is.integer(var2) | var2 < 1) {
    var2 <- type.convert(readline(prompt = "Enter v value (positive integer): "), as.is=TRUE)}
  (2^var1)*(3^var2)+1
}
```

or returning `NA`if conditions are not fulfilled:

```
pierpont <- function(pp) {
  var1 <- type.convert(readline(prompt = "Enter u value (positive integer): "), as.is=TRUE)
  var2 <- type.convert(readline(prompt = "Enter v value (positive integer): "), as.is=TRUE)
  if(is.integer(var1) & is.integer(var2) & var1 > 0 & var2 > 0) {
    (2^var1)*(3^var2)+1
  } else {
    NA
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

New plan, check if input is integer and > 0, only then return the result

```
pierpont <- function() {
  var1 <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Enter u value:"))
  var2 <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Enter v value:"))
  if (!is.na(var1) & !is.na(var2) &
      (var1 %% 1 == 0) & (var1 > 0) &
      (var2 %% 1 == 0) & (var2 > 0)) {
    (2^var1)*(3^var2)+1
  } else {
    "wroooong"
  }
}
```

Comment: Both `u` and `v` must be positive, its negation is `var1<0 || var2<0`.

Comment: This doesn't test if the input is integer. The `as.numeric` part after the loop also doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Roland That' also true.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the assumption that they are both postive integers by checking whether they are identical to their positive integer value:

```
pierpont <- function(pp){ 
  var1 <- readline(prompt = "Enter u value:"); 
  var2 <- readline(prompt = "Enter v value:"); 
  if(abs(as.integer(var1)+as.integer(var2))==var1+var2){
      return(c((2^var1)*(3^var2)+1))
  }else{return(NA)}
}
```